# Reusing MVC PartialView editor/display templates for action PartialViewResult

Tags: templates, model-view-controller, action, reusability, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view display template in `Views/DisplayTemplates` called `Bar.cshtml` so that it can be used like:

```
[DataType("Bar")]  
public FooBar Foo {get;set;}
```

Unfortunately if I want to use this in an action like `return PartialView("Bar",fooModel);` it won't find it because it's not in the list of folders searched. At the moment I've made a copy of the file and put it in `Views/DisplayTemplates` as well as `Views`, but is there a correct way of doing this with the one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I've done it now by providing a custom view engine that inherits from the razor view engine and simply adds the view locations to search through:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
        : this(null)
    {

    }

    public CustomViewEngine(IViewPageActivator activator)
        : base(activator)
    {
        var partialViewLocationFormatsList = PartialViewLocationFormats.ToList();

        partialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Views/{1}/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
        partialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Views/{1}/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
        partialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
        partialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml");

        PartialViewLocationFormats = partialViewLocationFormatsList.ToArray();

        var areaPartialViewLocationFormatsList = AreaPartialViewLocationFormats.ToList();

        areaPartialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
        areaPartialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
        areaPartialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
        areaPartialViewLocationFormatsList.Add("~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml");

        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = areaPartialViewLocationFormatsList.ToArray();
    }
}
}
```

And then registered it in Global.asax :

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use this in multiple pages you should create a folder in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`. And to use this template for your FooBar Foo property, decorate it with `[UIHint("Bar")]` attribute.

Comment: This doesn't help because UIHint is doing the same thing as DataType. The exception shows that it's not being looked for:
    InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=The partial view 'Bar' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Bar.aspx
~/Views/Home/Bar.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Bar.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Bar.ascx
~/Views/Home/Bar.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Bar.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Bar.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Bar.vbhtml

Comment: Is your Bar.cshtml in Views/DisplayTemplates or in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates or Views/Home/DisplayTemplates? The one that you specified is not being searched. If you are keeping it inside Views/DisplayTemplates try moving it to /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates or /Views/Home/DisplayTemplates

Comment: It's in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates, although it doesn't matter where I put it because MVC won't search in /DisplayTemplates, which is the problem